# How do i make checkboxes next to mSQL table data and submit the Selections?

Tags: php, html

I'm making a web app.  I have an html page in which i've displayed the data within an SQL table to the user.  Now i just need the user to select only 4 rows within the table, and then those selections will be submitted.

I have html and php code to help me retrieve and show the data within the table.
I have an html form that enables users to select via checkboxes.

here is some of the html:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Course Code</th>
            <th>Course Name</th>
            <th>Program</th>
            <th>Credits</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="registration" onclick="chkcontrol(0)" class="form-group">
            <td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="registration" onclick="chkcontrol(1)" class="form-group">
            <td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="registration" onclick="chkcontrol(2)" class="form-group">
            <td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="registration" onclick="chkcontrol(3)" class="form-group">
            <td>
        <tr>
    </table>
```

and here is the php:

```
<?php
        
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "student_login");
        if ($conn-> connect_error) 
        {
            die("Connection failed:". $conn-> connect_error);
        }
        
        //$form = "<form>";
        $sql = "SELECT Course_Code, Course_Name, Program, Credits from courses";
        $result = $conn-> query($sql);
        
        if ($result-> num_rows > 0) 
            {
                while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo "<tr><td>". $row["Course_Code"] ."</td><td>". $row["Course_Name"] ."</td><td>". $row["Program"] ."</td><td>". $row["Credits"] ."</td></tr>";
                }
                //echo "</table>"
            }   
            else
            {
                echo "0 result";
            }
            
        ?>
```

The output looks a little like this:

[image]

As you can see, the checkboxes are appearing above the actual table data.  How do i get the checkboxes to appear beside each row so that the User may select it? I can get the html, i just can't sort out the php code that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo a checkbox within each row along with the rest of the content:

```
echo "<tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' onchange='chkcontrol(\"". $row["Course_Code"] ."\")' class='form-group'></td>
    <td>". $row["Course_Code"] ."</td><td>". $row["Course_Name"] ."</td>
    <td>". $row["Program"] ."</td><td>". $row["Credits"] ."</td>
</tr>";
```

N.B. Having multiple items with the same `id` is invalid in HTML (since, by their nature, IDs must be unique!) so I've removed that from the markup.

And for checkboxes you should really handle `onchange` rather than `onclick`.

Also I wasn't sure of the purpose of the `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3` being passed to the `chkcontrol` function (since I don't know what the function does), so I've replaced them with with the course code on the assumption that that's a unique value, and that you maybe need to pass a unique value to the function in order to know what's been selected. It would help if you can clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, I understand correctly, but why don't you just echo checkboxes like that?

```
 echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' id='registration' onclick='chkcontrol(3)' class='form-group'>". $row["Course_Code"] ."</td><td>". $row["Course_Name"] ."</td><td>". $row["Program"] ."</td><td>". $row["Credits"] ."</td></tr>";
```